# Compare exact result in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, steam

I'm just about creating a website, where im iterating through a list of items in a JSON file. It looks like this:

```
"prices" : [
{
  "market_hash_name" : "★ Bayonet",
  "price" : 141.04,
  "created_at" : 1455877920
},
{
  "market_hash_name" : "AWP | Pit Viper (Minimal Wear)",
  "price" : "1.83",
  "created_at" : 1455878005
}
.
.
. and so on
```

Now, i'm sucessfull in searching and picking the "price" by the "market_hash_name" with a $ajax and a $each function in combination by jquery. Here it is:

```
$.ajax({url: "../json/priceapi.json", success: function(result){  // Get JSON File

$.each(result.prices, function(i, v) {    
   if (v.market_hash_name == market_hash_name) { ... // Parse JSON Data
```

Everything works fine, the code seems to be alright, but the problem is, that there, anywhere in this huge JSON File is a exact same second "market_hash_name" but with a additional text part. An exmaple:

```
{
  "market_hash_name" : "Souvenir AWP | Pit Viper (Minimal Wear)",                            
  "price" : "102.18",   // Additional text "Souvenir"
  "created_at" : 1455878414
},
```

Due this "double tag" the $each function tells me, that there are two results, for one key. I only want to have the exact result. Do you have any ideas how to do that? Is there a way to do something like this?

```
$.each(result.prices, function(i, v) {    
  if (v.market_hash_name - "Souvenir" == market_hash_name) { ...
```

Comment: Why you substract an string from  an string? That's not correct: `"string" - "string"`

Comment: "Souvenir AWP | Pit Viper (Minimal Wear)" does not equal "AWP | Pit Viper (Minimal Wear)", there is something else going on here.

Comment: @marcos You are right, its just for the understatement for a possible solution.

Comment: If there are duplicates of ` market_hash_name` the only way to get more precise is to have a second property to check. You should have unique identifiers for each item

Comment: Are you tried with regular expressions?

Comment: @JimEdelstein Hmm..ill look this up. Thx

Comment: I am not an regular expression expert, but here you are a little example: https://regex101.com/r/gT4oU9/1

Comment: You should rather identify products through IDs or similar, and they should not be duplicated, that's the best you can actually do (and probably the fastest solution) to actually be able to compare items. can you get / edit what is generating the json file?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks for that, ill have a look.

Comment: @briosheje The json file was downloaded as "price-api" from bitskins.com and saved locally by me to avoid online request..dont know if this is faster >.<

Comment: @briosheje i whish there would by id's for that..

Comment: @DanielBeller : Is the text always "Souvenir "? if so, this may help you: https://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/f68wfet6/1/ . Neither the best, nor the fastest, but it solves the problem.

Comment: @briosheje This looks good! Ill try it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to briosheje! https://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/f68wfet6/1/ works nice! Takes a bit, but i works :)

```
var res = {
    "prices": []
};

$.each(json.prices, function(i, e) {
    var exists = false;
  $.each(res.prices, function (c, f){
    console.log(f.market_hash_name + " <> " + e.market_hash_name);
    console.log(f.market_hash_name == e.market_hash_name);
    if (("Souvenir " + f.market_hash_name) == e.market_hash_name) {
        exists = true;
    }
  });

  !exists && res.prices.push(e);
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Be careful on big json files and much requests in short time